# VirtualHost Wildcard Subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain, virtualhost

I would like a virtual host file to show sites on a webserver so that if the url is http://site1.example.com then the folder is /var/www/html/site1 and another could be http://myblog.example.com and the folder is /var/www/html/myblog etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).